# Asymptotic expansion (Laplace Method) when Taylor series does not exist

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

So I've been struggling on calculating the asymptotic behaviour of the integral $$I(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty e^{-n(t+t^\alpha)}dt$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and where $\alpha$ is a real number and $\alpha\geq0$. Following the Laplace method and noting that the minima of $q(t)=t+t^\alpha$ is at $t=0$ over the integration interval, I attempted to Taylor expand only to realize that the series does not exist in general.

As far as I know of, one typically tries to form a power series and use this to evaluate the integral, but how does one do it when the Taylor series does not exist at the minimum? Or are there any another approaches which are reasonable at handling this kind of issues? Any help in either the specified integral or how to tackle these kind of questions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly,
$$
I(0) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - n(t + 1)} {\rm d}t}  = {\rm e}^{ - n} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - nt} {\rm d}t}  = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - n} }}{n}
$$
and
$$
I(1) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - n(t + t)} {\rm d}t}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - 2nt} {\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{{2n}}.
$$
Thus, I will assume that $\alpha\neq 0,1$. Consider first the case that $\alpha>1$. We make the change of variables
$$
t = s^\beta , \quad \beta  = \frac{1}{{\alpha  - 1}} ,
$$
and apply [Laplace's method](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iii) to deduce
$$
I(\alpha ) = \beta \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp\left( { - n(s^\beta   + s^{1 + \beta } )} \right)s^{\beta  - 1} {\rm d}s}  \sim \frac{\beta }{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{k}{\beta } + 1} \right)\frac{{b_k }}{{n^{k/\beta } }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, with
$$
b_k  = \frac{{( - 1)^k }}{\beta }\binom{k/\beta  + k}{k}.
$$
After simplification, we can write this expansion as
$$
I(\alpha ) \sim \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{\Gamma (\alpha k + 1)}}{{\Gamma (k + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^{(\alpha  - 1)k} }}} .
$$
If $0<\alpha<1$, then we make the change of variables
$$
t = s^{\gamma  + 1} ,\quad \gamma  = \frac{\alpha }{{1 - \alpha }},
$$
and apply Laplace's method to obtain
$$
I(\alpha ) = (\gamma  + 1)\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp\left( { - n(s^\gamma   + s^{1 + \gamma } )} \right)s^\gamma  {\rm d}s}  \sim \frac{{\gamma  + 1}}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{\gamma } + 1} \right)\frac{{c_k }}{{n^{(k + 1)/\gamma } }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, with
$$
c_k  = \frac{{( - 1)^k }}{\gamma }\binom{(k + 1)/\gamma  + k}{k}.
$$
After simplification, we can write this expansion as
$$
I(\alpha ) \sim \frac{1}{\alpha }\frac{1}{{n^{1/\alpha } }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k \frac{{\Gamma \big( {\frac{{k + 1}}{\alpha }} \big)}}{{\Gamma (k + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^{(1 - \alpha )k/\alpha } }}} .
$$
To leading order,
$$
I(\alpha ) \sim \frac{1}{n}
$$
for $\alpha>1$ and
$$
I(\alpha ) \sim \Gamma\! \left( {\frac{1}{\alpha } + 1} \right)\frac{1}{{n^{1/\alpha } }}
$$
for $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for but didn't really see how to do!

Comment: Hi again! I went through the calculations you gave above and managed to follow them excpet for the part where you calculated the coefficients $b_k$ and $c_k$. Did you get these from calculating the residual (2.3.18) in the link you provided? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1114191 Yes, write the residue as an integral, simplify it and you will see that it is just the Cauchy formula for the $k$th Taylor coefficient of a negative power binomial.

Comment: Ah, great! Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-n(t+t^\alpha)}dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty t'e^{-n(t+t^\alpha)}dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty t.n.(1+\alpha t^{\alpha-1})e^{-n(t+t^\alpha)}dt\\
\end{align}$$

Make a change of variable $x = n(t+t^\alpha)$.

We denote $t(x,n)$ the solution of the equation $t+t^\alpha = \frac{x}{n}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\infty t(x,n)e^{-x}dx\\
\end{align}$$

In general, $t(x,n)$ doesn't have analytical solution. So, we estimate an upper bound for $t(x,n)$. As the function $f(t) = t+t^{\alpha}$ is increasing, we have
$$t+t^\alpha = \frac{x}{n} \Longrightarrow t+t^\alpha<\frac{x}{n} + \left(  \frac{x}{n}\right)^\alpha \Longrightarrow t<\frac{x}{n} \tag{1}$$
and
$$t+t^\alpha =\left( \left(  \frac{x}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^\alpha  \Longrightarrow t+t^\alpha<\left(  \frac{x}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} + \left( \left(  \frac{x}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^\alpha  \Longrightarrow t<\left(  \frac{x}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\tag{2}$$

So,

$$(1) \Longrightarrow  I(\alpha)< \frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$(2) \Longrightarrow  I(\alpha)< \frac{1}{n^{1/ \alpha}}\int_0^\infty x^{1/ \alpha}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{n^{1/ \alpha}}\Gamma\left(1+ \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$$

Finally, we can conclude
$$I(\alpha) = \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{\max{\left\{1,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right\}}}}  \right)$$

Comment: I belive the OP would like to get an asymptotic expansion as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary The result is not an asymptotic expansion as $n\to +\infty$?

Comment: It is an order estimate. Do you know the definition of an asymptotic expansion due to Poincaré?

Comment: @Gary   $$I(\alpha) =\color{red}{0} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^{\max{\left\{1,\frac{1}{\alpha}\right\}}}}  \right)$$
with $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n x^n = 0$ ($N=1, a_0 = 0$)

Comment: Thanks! As Gary pointed out, it was the sort of answer he provided I was looking for. Sorry if not being clear enough.